# Java method reference resolving

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I'm trying to understand how method references work in java.
At first sight it is pretty straightforward. But not when it comes to such things:

There is a method in Foo class:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo merge(Foo another) {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

And in another class Bar there is a method like this:

```
public class Bar {
    public void function(BiFunction<Foo, Foo, Foo> biFunction) {
       //some logic
    }
}
```

And a method reference is used:

```
new Bar().function(Foo::merge);
```

It complies and works, but I don't understand how does it match this:

```
Foo merge(Foo another)
```

to BiFunction method:

```
R apply(T t, U u);
```

???

Comment: Is this a method in the class `Foo` ? If so, this would be (this, another) BiFunction.

Comment: If `merge(...)` is an instance method of `Foo`, then it has an implicit `this`-argument.

Comment: So I can treat `Foo merge(Foo another)` like `Foo merge(Foo this, Foo that)`? It isn't obvious.

Comment: @KirillBazarov it isn't at first glance. But if you know how method calls actually work and where methods are stored, it is somewhat obvious that there is an implicit `this` argument for each instance method. writing `someObject.doSomethingWith(someOtherObject)` is a convenient (and cognitive more appealing) alternative to `doSomethingWith(someObject, someOtherObject)`.

Comment: ... also called `Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type`

Comment: @KirillBazarov It's not that you can treat `Foo merge(Foo another)` like `Foo merge(Foo this, Foo another)`. That is exactly the way it is. You can even declare your `merge` method to receive `this`, and it will compile fine. It's just that who would explicitly declare an implicit `this` argument if it's not needed... But low level it's just the way it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an implicit `this` argument on instance methods. This is defined [§3.7 of the JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.7):

> The invocation is set up by first pushing a reference to the current instance, this, on to the operand stack. The method invocation's arguments, int values 12 and 13, are then pushed. When the frame for the addTwo method is created, the arguments passed to the method become the initial values of the new frame's local variables. That is, the reference for this and the two arguments, pushed onto the operand stack by the invoker, will become the initial values of local variables 0, 1, and 2 of the invoked method.

To understand why method invocation is done this way, we need to understand how the JVM stores code in memory. The code and the data of an object are separated. In fact, all methods of one class (static and non-static) are stored in the same place, the [method area (§2.5.4 of JVM spec)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4). This allows to store each method only once instead of re-storing them for each instance of a class over and over again. When a method like

```
someObject.doSomethingWith(someOtherObject);
```

is called, it gets actually compiled to something that looks more like

```
doSomething(someObject, someOtherObject);
```

Most Java-programmers would agree that `someObject.doSomethingWith(someOtherObject)` has a "lower cognitive complexity": we do something with `someObject` that involves `someOtherObject`. The center of this action is `someObject`, where `someOtherObject` is just a means to an end.

With `doSomethingWith(someObject, someOtherObject)`, you do not transport this semantics of `someObject` being the center of the action.

So in essence, we write the first version, but the computer prefers the second version.

As was pointed out by @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, you can even write the implicit `this` parameter explicitly since Java 8. The exact definition is given in [JLS, §8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1):

> The receiver parameter is an optional syntactic device for an instance method or an inner class's constructor. For an instance method, the receiver parameter represents the object for which the method is invoked. For an inner class's constructor, the receiver parameter represents the immediately enclosing instance of the newly constructed object. Either way, the receiver parameter exists solely to allow the type of the represented object to be denoted in source code, so that the type may be annotated. The receiver parameter is not a formal parameter; more precisely, it is not a declaration of any kind of variable (§4.12.3), it is never bound to any value passed as an argument in a method invocation expression or qualified class instance creation expression, and it has no effect whatsoever at run time.

The receiver parameter must be of the type of the class and must be named `this`.

This means that

```
public String doSomethingWith(SomeOtherClass other) { ... }
```

and

```
public String doSomethingWith(SomeClass this, SomeOtherClass other) { ... }
```

will have the same semantic meaning, but the latter allows for e.g. annotations.

Comment: Very helpful explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to understand with different types :

```
public class A {

    public void test(){
        function(A::merge);
    }

    public void function(BiFunction<A, B, C> f){

    }

    public C merge(B i){
        return null;
    }

    class B{}
    class C{}
}
```

We can know see that using a method reference `Test::merge` instead of a reference on an instance will implicitly use `this` as the first value.

---

[15.13.3. Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3)

> If the form is ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
>   [...]
>   If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then the target reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation method. Otherwise, there is no target reference.

And we can find some example using this behavior on the following subject:
The [JLS - 15.13.1. Compile-Time Declaration of a Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1) mention:

> A method reference expression of the form `ReferenceType::[TypeArguments] Identifier` can be interpreted in different ways.
>    - If `Identifier` refers to an instance method, then the implicit lambda expression has an extra parameter [...]
>    - if `Identifier` refers to a static method. It is possible for `ReferenceType` to have both kinds of applicable methods, so the search algorithm described above identifies them separately, since there are different parameter types for each case.

It then show some ambiguity possible with this behavior :

```
class C {
    int size() { return 0; }
    static int size(Object arg) { return 0; }

    void test() {
        Fun<C, Integer> f1 = C::size;
          // Error: instance method size() 
          // or static method size(Object)?
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe 15.13.3. explains it if my understanding of it is correct. Then 15.13.1 adds both interpretation of a `ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] idetifier` syntax. Please confirm or deny my undertanding (I am doubting it).